# Animation on part of item in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I am trying to implement a recycler view which will show items with rating and when ever rating changes it will flip the current rating with animation.

I am doing this on onBindView. The problem I am facing is, onBindView is called even view holder is partially visible ie. rating view is still not on screen and as a consequences it animate before its time.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for scroll events and determine which items have transitioned between non visible and fully visible.

Register a scroll callback with:

```
RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener
```

If you are using a LinearLayoutManager your callback can use the following methods to determine which items are visible:

```
LinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition
LinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition
```

It is up to you to track the changes in item state between non-visible and visible.

Comment: Can I get ViewHolder later?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findViewByPosition(int)